# Anchor executes different function that it is assigned to

Tags: jquery

For some reason a href with class RemoveSpell after clicking executes on a.AddSpell again. You can test out the problem here http://89.69.172.125/cms2.0/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    championNumber = 1;
    $('a#AddChampion').on('click',function(){

        $('div#ChampionInput').append(
        '<div class="Champion">\
             <a href="#" class="Remove">Remove</a>\
             <br>\
             <input type="text" class="ChampionInput" name="champion[]" placeholder="Champion '+championNumber+'">\
             <a href="#" class="AddSpell">Add Spell</a>\
             <br>\
         <div>');
        championNumber++;
    });
    $('div#ChampionInput').on('click', 'a.Remove',function(){
        $(this).parent('div.Champion').remove();

    });
    $('div#ChampionInput').on('click', 'a.AddSpell',function(){
        $(this).append(
        '<div class="Spell">\
            <br>\
            <input type="text">\
            <a href="#" class="RemoveSpell">Remove Spell</a>\
        </div>\
        ');
    });
    $('div#ChampionInput').on('click', 'a.RemoveSpell',function(){

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not add the remove spell as a child of `addSpell` element, need to insert it after that

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  championNumber = 1;
  $('a#AddChampion').on('click', function() {

    $('div#ChampionInput').append(
      '<div class="Champion">\
    <a href="#" class="Remove">Remove</a>\
    <br>\
    <input type="text" class="ChampionInput" name="champion[]" placeholder="Champion ' + championNumber + '">\
    <a href="#" class="AddSpell">Add Spell</a>\
    <br>\
   <div>');
    championNumber++;
  });
  $('div#ChampionInput').on('click', 'a.Remove', function() {
    $(this).parent('div.Champion').remove();

  });
  $('div#ChampionInput').on('click', 'a.AddSpell', function() {
    $(this).after(
      '<div class="Spell">\
   <br>\
   <input type="text">\
   <a href="#" class="RemoveSpell">Remove Spell</a>\
  </div>\
  ');
  });
  $('div#ChampionInput').on('click', 'a.RemoveSpell', function() {
    $(this).closest('.Spell').remove();
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 900px;
}
input {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
.ChampionInput {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="AddChampion">Add Champion</a>
<form name="second_form" id="second_form" method="POST">
  <div id="ChampionInput">
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Several problems. Invalid html nesting and not recognizing that events that occur on a descendent of an element will also trigger event handlers on the parent.

Events propagate up the DOM tree. So when you nest `removeSpell` inside `addSpell` and click `removeSpell` the event will also trigger on `addSpell`

This is in fact how you are delegating events using `on()`. You are assigning the event handler to `div#ChampionInput` which is up the DOM tree from both of these elements. This delegation relies on the event propagation or "bubbling" up from the targets

You can't have `<a>` as a descendent of `<a>`.